# Copying a QThread pointer using a memcpy in a copy constructor

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I have a vector of QThread pointers(vector) as a class member. I want to declare the copy constructor for this class. Now i want to "deep copy" the contents of vector. QThread API does not a have a copy constructor of it own, so i was wondering how can i "copy" the contents of the pointer vector. Is memcpy the best approach to do this? Are there any other APIs available out there which are better than memcpy to tackle this problem?

Comment: Copying a thread doesn't make much sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this copy?

Comment: Usually memcpy is quite the opposite of a deep copy

Comment: If a class doesn't have a copy constructor, that is a pretty good indication that you  are not supposed to copy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should be making a deep copy of this class. The concept of 'deep copying' a QThread makes no sense, as each QThread instance will own/manage a system-level thread the state of which cannot be simply copied to another object.

It sounds like the class you are copying is a fairly integral component of your application, and therefore copying it seems unreasonable. Copy constructors tend to be more reasonable on classes that are largely data-based.

The only way that makes some sense to proceed down this path is to copy the pointers themselves, rather than the QThread objects themselves, but for the reasons aforementioned, I would be very careful with this, and consider carefully why you are doing this.